# How to dismiss a view controller behind the current view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a view controller that asks the user to enter a password. If the correct password is entered, another view displaying some data is pushed. When the data view is closed, the program displays the password enter view (since it was never dismissed). However, I would like the password enter view to also have been dismissed, so that the program then displays the original view before the password enter view.

I have tried dismissing the password enter view in `prepare(for: ...)` when the segue to the data view occurs, and I have also tried passing the password enter view as a delegate to the data view, and dismissing the password enter view before dismissing the data view when the user presses the exit button. Neither of these solutions actually dismiss the password enter view.

Comment: try `popToRootViewController`

Comment: That didn't work. Possibly because the view hierarchy goes original view controller -> password enter view -> navigation controller -> data view

Comment: `dismissViewControllerAnimated` your passwordEnterVC

Comment: `dismissViewControllerAnimated` has been renamed to `dismiss`, which is what I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the data view, you can use an **unwind segue** from data view to the original view controller, so that password enter view will also be dismissed when the segue is trigged.